# What is special about the 73-88% Barrows reward potential range?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

Something I've noticed about RuneLite is that the reward potential percentage color for the Barrows plugin changes at certain thresholds. Digging into the source code, the line that does this is this one:

```
.rightColor(rewardPercent >= 73.0f && rewardPercent <= 88.0f ? Color.GREEN : rewardPercent < 65.6f ? Color.WHITE : Color.YELLOW)
```

This line sets the completion percentage color to white below 65.6%, yellow between 65.6% and 73%, green between 73% and 88%, and yellow again above 88%. What, in particular, is different about this particular range, and how does this percentage factor into the loot roll?

Comment: From what Ive gathered from the wiki, that range is basically the range where you will get the max amount of runes, but no bolt racks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit more research on the [barrows wiki page](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Barrows#Rewards). It states that:

> If players wish to receive more runes (which are generally worth more
>   coins) instead of bolt racks and key halves, they should aim for a
>   Reward Potential of 880. Having exactly 880 points maximises the
>   quantity of blood runes without having bolt racks take up reward
>   slots.

So this accounts for the max of 88%. But what about the 73%? Well, further down the page it states that the roll for blood runes:

> Requires 756 reward potential to roll.

So 73-88 is essentially the best range to have to get the max amount of mind, chaos, and death runes, while also still guaranteeing a roll for potential blood runes. At 88%, you can receive the max amount of runes possible (if you are so lucky). After 88% (exactly 881 potential) you will roll for bolt racks and lose a potential reward slot for runes.

Just as a quick guide, these are the potentials needed to roll for each rune/bolt drop.

1. Mind runes require 381 reward potential to roll.
2. Chaos runes require 506 reward potential to roll.
3. Death runes require 631 reward potential to roll.
4. Blood runes require 756 reward potential to roll.
5. Bolt racks require 881 reward potential to roll.
6. Key halves require 1006 reward potential to roll.
7. Dragon med helm requires 1012 reward potential to roll.

*Note: The chance for a piece of barrows equipment is "unaffected by the rewards potential that is built by killing other monsters in the crypt."*

Comment: Do you still have a 1/33 chance to get a piece in this range I assume? As long as it's a 6 brother run?

Comment: Yes, further down in the rewards section it states that the roll for a barrows item is separate from all of this other stuff. Ill edit that in to my answer